# select now() from table, why do we specify a table?

Tags: sql, mysql

whats the point of specifying a table if `now()` is going to be the same for any table.??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know FROM was needed in the SQL-92 standard (at least; that was the version I was able to find with [some nice BNF grammar](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html) moments ago).

Maybe the logic behind was "functions" should use tables for producing output, so you have to specify something. In fact, I see quite low practical value in a query that only outputs the actual time.

Comment: There is a practical use in selecting current time. What if you want to know db server's time? What if you use stored procedures?

Comment: If I would like to know the time on the db server it's okay, but if I would like to get some administrative information on my db server, I would query time with several other things together, not the time alone. That's why I said I can't see the point in querying the time in itself.

Comment: What if you use windows application and you don't have any application server. How do you get current time? Do you get it from user's computer or db server's time? Maybe you doesn't have cases when you need db time, but there are cases when you really need it.

Answer (score 7):

Try without specifying table, like this

```
SELECT NOW()
```

There are also

**CURDATE()** and **CURTIME()**

More on this

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp

**EDIT:** The same way in MS SQL, you can write a query like

```
SELECT getdate()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to; you can just `SELECT Now()`

However, people tend to use it in conjunction with querying for fields from actual tables, and that's why you see it `FROM TABLE` so often.

This is in re: MySQL 5

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you can query `SELECT now()`